# Trying to make draggable form elements horizontal jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Can someone tell me how I make draggable images appear horizontal without loosing functionality. If I set the style to horizontal the images are no longer draggable. I'm using jQuery & jQueryUI to implement the form.

JQuery

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){

$(function() {


$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
  placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
  cursor: 'crosshair',
  update: function(event, ui) {
    var order = $("#sortable").sortable("toArray");
    order = JSON.stringify(order);
    correct = JSON.stringify(["4","3","2","1"]);
    if (!order==correct){
      var valid = false
        console.log(':(');
    }
    else {
       var valid = true;
    }
  }
});

$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();


$('#submit').on('click', function() {
var valid = true,
    message = '';

$('form input').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if(!$this.val()) {
        var inputName = $this.attr('name');
        valid = false;
        message += 'Please enter your ' + inputName + '\n';
    }
});

if(!valid) {
    alert(message);
}
else {
  window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
}
});
});
});
</script>
```

Html Form

```
<body>
<form action="" method="post" class="a">

Name : <input type="text" class="text" name="name" id="name" /> <br/>
Address : <input type="text" class="text" name="address" id="address" /> <br/>
email : <input type="text" class="text" name="email" id="email" /> <br/>

<input type="hidden" id="image_order" name="image_order" value="order" />
<ul id="sortable" style="width: 524px;">

<li id="1" class="ui-state-default"><img src="1.png" width="100" height="90" /></li>
<li id="2" class="ui-state-default"><img src="2.png" width="100" height="90" /></li>
<li id="3" class="ui-state-default"><img src="3.png" width="100" height="90" /></li>
<li id="4" class="ui-state-default"><img src="4.png" width="100" height="90" /></li>  

</ul>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<input name="Submit" value="RE-ORDER" type="submit" />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to add style `display: inline-block` to the `li` element like this

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;    // This just to give some space between the image
}
```

the other image will take the space left when one image is dragged, if you want the dragged one to keep the space, give `width` to the `li` the same with your `image width` (If all of the image has the same width).

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;    // This just to give some space between the image
    width: 100px;    // To reserve the space
}
```

Here's the working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/btdd4udw/)

### Edit:

To answer more about your question in the comment, the main issue that cause your validation to be valid is because you're using the same variable `valid` and individiual in their own context inside `sortable update` and `submit onclick`, thus causing your validation to say valid if you've fill all the input field, to fix this, you need to declare their own variable in the start, and change it's value with your validation, the changed code become like this:

```
$(function () {
    var validInput, validSort;    // Added this line

    $("#sortable").sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        cursor: 'crosshair',
        update: function (event, ui) {
            var order = $("#sortable").sortable("toArray");
            order = JSON.stringify(order);
            correct = JSON.stringify(["4", "3", "2", "1"]);
            if (order == correct) {
                validSort = true    // Changed this line
                console.log(':)');
            }
            else {
                validSort = false;    // Added this line
            }
        }
    });

    $("#sortable").disableSelection();


    $('#submit').on('click', function () {
        validInput = true,    // Changed this line
            message = '';

        $('form input').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            if (!$this.val()) {
                var inputName = $this.attr('name');
                validInput = false;     // Changed this line
                message += 'Please enter your ' + inputName + '\n';
            }
        });

        if (!validInput) {
            alert(message);
            console.log("not valid");
        } else if(!validSort) {    // Added this line
            alert("Sort Not Valid");
            //window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
            console.log("not valid");
        }
        else {       
            alert("Valid Submit");
            console.log("valid");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here's the working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/btdd4udw/2/)

Comment: Awh thank you. I was stuck on that for far too long. Also do you have any idea how I would prevent the form from submitting if the oder of the array of images is not equal to correct? Right now even with an if else statement it seems to be allowing me to submit whether or not the order is equal to correct.

Comment: @user2003341 if in your `form` you already mentioned the `action`, then put `return false;` inside not valid statement, but if you don't specify the `action`, put the `return false;` in the end of `click` function. You should probably set the `action` though because you use `input type="submit"`

Comment: So what exactly do you mean set the action? Like valid = false; I put the if statement for the array at the end of the click function but it still doesn't seem to be working correctly.

Comment: @user2003341 `<form action="target_url" method="post" class="a">` it's your code, the `action` is the url that it will open after you click submit, if you try it in the `fiddle` it won't work because it can't find the page you're targeting. Here's the example in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/btdd4udw/1/)

Comment: But it still returns valid if the images are in the wrong order? Am I missing something? Also this seems to affect my re-order button. Sorry I'm very new to javaScript & jQuery this is my first attempt. I don't want to us plugins

Comment: How is this affecting my re-order?

Comment: @user2003341, sorry for the late reply. Edited the answer to comply more of your question. And as for the re-order button, when I start the fiddle with your code, it doesn't seems to work either. I'll check for it again later.